# AWS IoT MQTT rootca.pem not found

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, aws-sdk, mqtt

I have this error when I try to connect to my thing in AWS

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/labs/p11/test.py", line 27, in <module>
    my_rpi.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/MQTTLib.py", line 403, in connect
    return self._mqttCore.connect(keepAliveIntervalSecond)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/mqttCore.py", line 287, in connect
    self._pahoClient.tls_set(self._cafile, self._cert, self._key, ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)  # Throw exception...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/paho/client.py", line 600, in tls_set
    raise IOError(ca_certs+": "+err.strerror)
IOError: rootca.pem: No such file or directory
```

This is my code that I use to run

```
# Import SDK packages 
from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTClient 
from time import sleep 
from gpiozero import MCP3008 
adc = MCP3008(channel=0) 
# Custom MQTT message callback 
def customCallback(client, userdata, message): 
  print("Received a new message: ") 
  print(message.payload) 
  print("from topic: ") 
  print(message.topic) 
  print("‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐\n\n") 
   
host = "YourEndPoint.amazonaws.com" 
rootCAPath = "rootca.pem" 
certificatePath = "certificate.pem.crt" 
privateKeyPath = "private.pem.key" 
my_rpi = AWSIoTMQTTClient("basicPubSub") 
my_rpi.configureEndpoint(host, 8883) 
my_rpi.configureCredentials(rootCAPath, privateKeyPath, certificatePath) 
my_rpi.configureOfflinePublishQueueing(-1)  # Infinite offline Publish queueing 
my_rpi.configureDrainingFrequency(2)  # Draining: 2 Hz 
my_rpi.configureConnectDisconnectTimeout(10)  # 10 sec 
my_rpi.configureMQTTOperationTimeout(5)  # 5 sec 
# Connect and subscribe to AWS IoT 
my_rpi.connect() 
my_rpi.subscribe("sensors/light", 1, customCallback) 
sleep(2) 
# Publish to the same topic in a loop forever 
loopCount = 0 
while True: 
    light = round(1024‐(adc.value*1024)) 
  my_rpi.publish("sensors/light", str(light), 1) 
  sleep(5)
```

So my code is about retrieving light from my GPIO, send it to the MQTT broker(AWS) then send it to my Gmail.

I have ensured that paho-mqtt is installed, AWSIoTPythonSDK is installed. The 3 files, rootca.pem, certificate.pem.crt, private.pem.key are in the same folder as the python file above. Is there a reason that cause the error above?

Comment: Try to specify a full path for the cert,key and rootca files.

Answer (score 1):

after .pem there should be a .crt or.key also that is usually hidden in your file directory so its hard to notice and write the full path.